# Page expiring while trying deleting created APIs

Tags: json, laravel, api

I am creating my data **API** using the **Laravel** Resource. And testing the methods in Postman. Now when I am trying to fetch data from database and show them, it is working fine both in Postman and Browser.
But when I am trying the `delete` method, using postman, providing the URL as per I defined in my routes and selecting the method `delete`, it **returns** me:

> "419 Page Expired"

Here is my **route** for delete:

```
Route::delete('feed/api/{id}', 'FeedController@destroy');
```

Here is the function in **controller**:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $feed = Feeds::findOrFail($id);
    if ($feed->delete()) {
        return new FeedResource($feed);
    }           

}
```

**Note:** If I use the route in my `api.php` file instead of `web.php`, it works. But I don't want to keep that in `api.php`. Because the routes in `api.php` don't work if middleware checked.

Comment: Are you including the csrf token?

Comment: may be you are missing csrf field

Answer (score 0):

For api you must exclude routes from csrf check for apis  in VerifyCsrfToken.php